# Neo4j cypher queries, counting nodes and two way relationships

Tags: neo4j, nodes, relationship, counting

I’m trying to run a **cypher** query on nodes with two way relationships and would like to count each of those relationships as well.

**Example:**

```
Nodes: store + customer 
Relationships: sold + bought
```

In an ideal scenario, I’d want to see both relationships connecting the store and customer. 
However, there are cases when only the customer is reporting they bought from the store, and vice versa when only the store is reporting they sold to the customer, but the customer hasn’t verified that sale.

**I’d like to return the following:**

- Store name
- count of sold & bought relationships (store <—> customer)
- count of only sold relationships (store —> customer)
- count of only bought relationship (store <— customer)

*** Clarification:

for example, it would be 10 stores with 7-10 customers each, and yes in Neo it would be two different arcs connecting:

[store-customer r/ships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DydOB.jpg)

the goals is to look at the different reporting practices for each store, as some stores may say they sold when they haven't, and customers may say they bought items. How often do each of those scenarios occur?

Comment: What are your inputs and expected outputs? Is the query only for a single store and a single customer, or a single store and all its customers? For your outputs, do you want the count across all customers per store, or the counts per customer of the store (where you'll have a row per customer)?

Comment: Do really need to have relationships in both directions? In neo4j, traversing a relationship backwards is just as easy and fast as traversing it forwards. So, it would seem you only need one relationship type (either `sold`, or `bought`, but not both).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like

```
match (n:Store)<-[r:bought]-(n1:Customer)<-[r1:sold]-(n) with count(distinct r) as verified 
match (n:Store)<-[r:bought]-(n1:Customer) with verified, count(distinct r) - verified as boughtOnly 
match (n:Store)-[r:sold]->(n1:Customer) with verified, boughtOnly, count(distinct r) - verified as soldOnly 
return verified, soldOnly, boughtOnly
```

See the dummy database [here](http://console.neo4j.org/r/6o4gym) to test on

**EDIT**
Updated query with where clause and returning `store` info

```
match (n:Store) where n.state = 'MA' and n.city = 'Boston' with n as Store
match (Store)<-[r:bought]-(n1:Customer)<-[r1:sold]-(n) with Store, count(distinct r) as verified 
match (Store)<-[r:bought]-(n1:Customer) with Store, verified, count(distinct r) - verified as boughtOnly 
match (Store)-[r:sold]->(n1:Customer) with Store, verified, boughtOnly, count(distinct r) - verified as soldOnly 
return verified, soldOnly, boughtOnly, Store
```

Comment: would it be possible to return the store name as well, and to make the cypher query more efficient computationally, insert a where clause on the node property like

where n.state = 'MA' and n.city = 'Boston'

when I do that I get the following error:
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Variable `n` not defined (line 4, column 7 (offset: 308))
"where n.state = 'MA' and n.city = 'Boston'"

Comment: Yes, that's possible, but because the `with` clause only keeps the nodes/relationships stated there, `n` is not available there. You can include the where clause before the different `with` statements or keep the `n` node.
But before you continue, have a second look at the comment of @cybersam whether you really need two-way relationships.

Answer (score 0):

It's as easy as this :

```
MATCH (n:Customer)
RETURN 
size((n)-[:BOUGHT|:SOLD]-()) AS bothRels,
size((n)-[:BOUGHT]-()) AS boughtRels,
size((n)-[:SOLD]-()) AS soldRels
```

```
╒══════════╤════════════╤══════════╕
│"bothRels"│"boughtRels"│"soldRels"│
╞══════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│2         │1           │1         │
└──────────┴────────────┴──────────┘
```